# Flutter: How are images passed to native side?

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

I am building a plugin and need to make use of images (like Image.asset or Image.file) and need to pass them to my native plugin. However, I could not find a decent way to pass these.
Does anyone know how to achieve that and how these objects are used natively in general?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the asset path and read it via Flutter:

1. Pass the asset path through `MethodChannel`
2. Look for the asset using it's path:

```
AssetManager assetManager = registrar.context().getAssets();
String key = registrar.lookupKeyForAsset("icons/heart.png");
AssetFileDescriptor fd = assetManager.openFd(key);
```

[Flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#loading-flutter-assets-in-android)